# Best practice for caching public NUGET packages on Azure Artifacts NUGET Server

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, frameworks, nuget

What is the best practice to publish a cached version of a public NUGET package available to a Visual Studio .NET Framework project to a private NUGET server, such as on the  Azure Devops Artifacts NUGET server?

I have spent a significant amount of time researching this, and have not found any articles that answer the question effectively.  None of the answers presented when I started this question provide the answer.

I know how to publish private NUGET packages.  I just need to know what is the accepted practice to get a version of a public package to be consumed from a private NUGET server by a Visual Studio .NET Framework project.

Comment: You could use [upstream sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#cached-metadata), which is morel like binding a public feed to the private feed.

Comment: Thanks Perry.  I am aware of the upstream feature of a private NUGET server using Azure DEVOPS artifacts.  I am trying to see if there is a best practice to keep one version of a NUGET package on the NUGET private server, so if it changes (or is removed), it will not impact the build.  Because NUGET package versions are supposed to be immutable, it could be that is all that is needed.  Regarding Visual Studio builds, after the NUGET package is installed, if the project is rebuilt, even after a NUGET restore, it will still use the version of the package that was installed.